# Ugee M708 tablet no longer working with Paint Tool Sai

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-tablet

I've recently realised that my Ugee M708 tablet doesn't work anymore with Paint Tool Sai despite it working well before.

I've just now reinstalled the latest drivers (latest on ugee website was a few weeks ago) but paint tool sai still won't work. If I have paint tool sai focused, the pen will not longer move the mouse.

It was working fine yesterday and I never did anything to it in terms of it's drivers. The time I noticed it wasn't working was shortly after restarting my computer to finalise the installation of my audio drivers that were out of date.

Other programs like photoshop and medibang paint pro still work fine.

Paint tool sai is ran as administrator (it seems it won't run without doing that anyway) and so is my tablet configuration program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only fix I know of is going into the paint tool SAI folder and opening 'misc'
Then change "TabletMouseSimulation = 0" to "TabletMouseSimulation = 1" . That should fix the pen not moving.. but currently I have come across another problem with the stabilizer not working (after using this fix to stop the pen from not working) and its really frustrating me im considering getting a wacom x_x